# CUPS with Zebra printer doesn't print

Tags: linux, printing, zebra-printers, cups

EDIT:

I have found that the EPL2 driver allows for a partial print and crashes the printer after. Still no useful printing though

--------------------------

I have a Zebra printer (LP2844) hooked up to an RPI, with Jessie installed. The printer used to work with the direct USB connection and the CUPS service.

I tried adding a second one, but couldn't get it to work. After a day of fiddling I wanted to revert to the first setup. But now, even with one printer I can not get it to print even a test page.

The state in CUPS goes from "Rendering page 1" to "Rendering complete" and the job then disappears. CUPS believes the job to be completed successfully and the error_log is not appended.

I have been trying to switch the drivers between the ZPL driver and a raw driver. Previous to the second printer, I used the raw driver.

Windows seems to be able to print pages on the Zebra via USB connection.

I am totally at a loss here. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: LP2844 is not a ZPL printer. ZPL or Raw mode will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the printer was broken for some reason after adding a second one. Had to "recalibrate" the autosense feature.

Followed: https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO8281

> Auto Sense Procedure
>
> 1. Make sure you have configured your driver or application for the media type you are using. Gap/Web or Black Bar (Mark). Send a test
>      print to the printer before proceding so it is properly configured.
>      Note: You can only send data when the button is green so cycle power
>      if the printer button is red. 2 Turn off printer and have media loaded
> 2. Hold feed button down, and turn printer back on
> 3. When the red light starts flashing, release the feed button.
> 4. Printer light will turn green and advance a few blanks.
> 5. After printer stops advancing and prints the internal information, press the feed button one time.
> 6. You will get another label with the "Out of Dump" message on it.
>
> The printer should feed one label each time you press the Feed Button.
>   If one label is issued each time you press the Feed Button the printer
>   has been properly calibrated.
>
> Skipping labels or printing across multiple labels
>
> If the printer is properly calibrated but still issues multiple labels
>   when printing then assure your label setup for printing is set to the
>   correct label size. If it is longer than the calibrated length the
>   printer will print additional labels attempting to print the complete
>   image. Allow for a small dead band if this is occurring by shortening
>   your driver/software label size.